# How to properly validate your class

Tags: spring, validation

I have a simple class for registering an address

```
@Data
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class ColorDto {
    @Size(min = 2, max = 100, message = "The size must be in the range 2 to 100")
    private String colorName;
}
```

On my form, I add an object of this class and all the entities already in the database:

```
List<ColorDto> colors = colorService.getAll();
        model.addAttribute("colors", colors);
        model.addAttribute("colorForm", new ColorDto());
        return "color";
```

The form itself looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Colors</title>
</head>
<body>
<h2>Colors</h2>
<div th:each="color : ${colors}">
    <p>
        Name : <span th:text="*{color.colorName}"></span>
    </p>
</div>
<h4>Add new color</h4>
<div>
    <form th:method="POST" th:action="@{/product/color}" th:object="${colorForm}">
        <tr>
            <td>Enter color:</td>
            <td><input type="text" th:field="*{colorName}" required/></td>
            <div th:if="${colorError}">
                <div style="color: red" th:text="${colorError}"></div>
            </div>
            <div style="color:red" th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('colorName')}" th:errors="*{colorName}" >color error</div>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input name="submit" type="submit" value="submit" /></td>
        </tr>
    </form>
</div>
<p><a href="/">Home</a></p>
</body>
</html>
```

I process data from this form in the following method:

```
@PostMapping("/color")
    public String addNewColor(@ModelAttribute("colorForm") @Valid ColorDto colorDto,
                              HttpSession httpSession,
                              BindingResult bindingResult,
                              Model model){
        if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
            return "color";
        }
```

If I fill in the field correctly, the method works. If I send invalid data there, the program does not process this data. That is, it does not enter the method at all and Http Status 400 is issued.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try change order of the parameters in the `addNewColor` function so the `bindingResult` is immediately after the validated parameter?

Like this:

```
    @PostMapping("/color")
    public String addNewColor(HttpSession httpSession,
                              @ModelAttribute("colorForm") @Valid ColorDto colorDto,
                              BindingResult bindingResult,
                              Model model){
        if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
            return "color";
        }
```